# Cannot Style Nextjs Component (Link) using styled-components

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components, server-side-rendering

I am trying to styled `Link` Component provided by `NextJS` using `Styled-Components`.
I have done all the setup including `babel-plugin-styled-components`, creating `_document.js` in `/pages`. But still I am unable to Style the link component.

For setup, I have followed this article: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/using-next-js-with-styled-components-easy-dfff3849e4f1

This is working fine

```
const StyledComponent = Styled.a`
    color: red;
`
```

But this does not

```
const StyledComponent = Styled(Link)`
    color: red;
`
```

Can anyone pls tell me what am I missing? What has to be done now?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The next.js `Link` doesn't take any styles but you can style the children eg `a` and add `passHref` to the `Link` when using a `custom compoment`. The styles of the child will be applied to the parent i.e `Link`. However, you can style the react-router-dom `Link, NavLink` like what you did above. In next.js you can do it like this

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const CustomLink = styled.a `
    color: white;
    background: red;
`

<Link href="/" passHref>
    <CustomLink>Home</CustomLink>
</Link>
```